# How to get files from a Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 5.1 to a computer with Windows 10 by USB

Tags: usb, 5.1-lollipop, windows, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-6

How is it possible to transfer file over USB from an Android phone to a computer?

Situation: Windows 10, Galaxy s6 Edge on Android 5.1.1.

(I've read articles, followed dozens of tutorials, installed drivers, on differents winX computers, upgraded a lot of things, and it still doesn't work.)

Comment: And what was your actual problem that you were trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is currently not compatible to galaxy s6 edge.

I've made it works on some windows 10 computers sometimes, but sometimes there is nothing to do to make it works.

If you want to be able to connect your phone to your computer, do not *upgrade* to windows 10.